# FirebaseRTC login fails

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-cli

I am trying to learn video conferencing app for which I am developing webRTC app using following link.

https://webrtc.org/getting-started/firebase-rtc-codelab

But I get stuck at the step 4. Install the Firebase Command Line Interface, for firebase login. It shows me error as follows in browser.

> Oops!
>   Firebase CLI Login Failed The Firebase CLI login request was
>   rejected or an error occurred. Please run firebase login again or
>   contact support if you continue to have difficulty logging in.

It generates authentication code also, but I paste it and then shows following error in terminal.

> Error: Authentication Error: Your credentials are no longer valid.
>   Please run firebase login --reauth
>
> For CI servers and headless environments, generate a new token with
>   firebase login:ci

Tried all the solutions, but no luck. FYI - I login with my google account.

firebase login --reauth, gives same error after pasting the authentication code.
firebase login:ci, gives same error after login with google account.

Can anyone help into this?

Comment: *"Tried all the solutions"* - please edit the question to state exactly the things you tried.  The error message is telling you what to do, but we need to be able to see that you've done it, and the result of what you did.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0):

try

`firebase logout forebase login`